# Entity framework Optimistic Concurrency Exception

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency

Should I maintain a `Timestamp property` on my Model classes for enable **optimistic concurrency** for data update and delete ?  If I won't use such a attribute,whether EF will give concurrency exception at run time  or not ?

Is this must for enable the concurrency handling ?

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, either that or you decorate a property with `[ConcurencyCheck]`. Otherwise you will end up with scenario last write wins.

**EDIT:**

Official tutorial on how to handle Concurrency:

[Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Can you say the must be needed situation for handle concurrency issues (I mean some examples)?

Comment: Yes you must use either [TimeStamp] or [ConcurrencyCheck]. Then you need to decide how would you deal with Concurrency. Warn user? Reload from database and merge? I've added a tutorial in post for you which has extensive explanation.